# Best approach for developing a stateful computation-heavy application with a rest-api interface using python?

Tags: python, web-applications, microservices, web-services, django

I want to develop an end-to-end machine learning application where data will be in GPU-memory and computations will run on the GPU. A stateless RESTfull service with a database is not desirable since the traffic between GPU-memory and database will destroy the "purpose" of it being fast.

The way I see it is that I need a way to "serve" the class (let's call it as experiment class) which has the data and the methods, then call them using rest APIs.

Right now I am using FastApi and initialize the experiment class in it which I believe is not optimal. My class (as well as the data) lives in FastAPI runtime. Kinda like,

```
import experiment_class
import FastApi

app = FastAPI()
my_experiment = expertiment_class()

@app.get("/load_csv")
my_experiment.load_csv("some_file_path")

// do some more on the data
...
```

There are two problems I am having a hard time with,

One of them is the terminology:

- Is this really a stateful application?
- Is there a word to describe what I am doing? Is this a "Model, View, Controller" design, can it be a simple "Server-Client" or is it something completely different?
- Do I need a "Web-server", a "Web-framework" or a "Web-service" for this?

Another one is what technology I can use for this :

- Is it okay to use FastAPI like this?
- Do I set up an RPC server (Remote Procedure Call) and call it using Rest API?
- Is WSGI or an ASGI server suitable for this task?
- Are Django, Flask, Tornado like web frameworks only used for stateless apps? Because nearly all of the examples are.
- Do I stick to bare bone Python where I use threads or BaseManager servers?

P.S. What I meant with end-to-end machine learning is that I should be able to load data, process it, and give it to the model for training all the while without leaving the GPU-memory. You can think of a Jupyter-notebook, but we call the cells with rest API.

Answer (score 2):

Stateful means your server has awareness of client and it's state. Instead of thinking in terms of services (SOAP or Rest) think in terms of web application. Change in thinking the way you do will change your perspective the way you are looking at solution.